# How to fix "used reverse() to map through data pulled form API call (stored in redux state) [Javascript Redux/React]"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reverse

this.props.playedGames pulls from my Redux State and is ordered most recent date to first entry (descending order). I need the data for my cumulative line chart (chart.js) to be in the opposite order first entry to most recent date. 
How would I do this without using the reverse method which continuously reverses upon each refresh. I would rather not re call the API as I have the data I need.

I have tried creating a state for when page refreshes so it will not refresh. I have tried several different ways of this. All failed.

my code:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';

class ChartPage extends Component {
profitForChart = (props) => {
    let total = 0
    return this.props.playedGames.reverse().map( (game, index) => ({
      x: index,
      y: total += parseFloat(game.profit)

    }))
  } 
render() {
   if(!this.props.playedGames) return <h1>Loading...</h1>
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const data = {
      datasets: [{
        data: this.profitForChart(),
        label: 'PROFIT'
    }],
    labels: this.props.playedGames.map( game => (new Date(game.start_date_time)).toLocaleDateString()),
  }
  return(
      <div className={classes.root}

            <Line data={data} />

      </div>
  )
 }
}
const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
  return {
    playedGames: state.userPlayedGames.playedGames,
    isLoading: state.isLoading,
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
}
ChartPage.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
export default  compose(
  withStyles(styles, {
    name: 'ChartPage',
  }),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(withRouter(ChartPage));
```

Expected result: 
1/2018, 2/2018, 3/2018 with cumulative line graph going up over time.

Actual result: 
(is correct on initial load and every other refresh) but the next one is wrong: the graph cumulative is inverse and the dates go backwards: 3/2018, 2/2018, 1/2018. -----

Answer (score 1):

Let assume api gives following response,

```
const response = [{x: 3, y: 5, date: '1/2/2018'}, {x: 3, y: 5, date: '1/4/2019'}, {x: 3, y: 5, date: '1/4/2013'}, {x: 3, y: 5, date: '1/2/2016'}]
```

Now, we can sort this by date using sort function.

```
response
   .sort((a,b) => new Date(a.date) > new Date(b.date) ? -1 : 0)
   .map(// use your above code)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did not actually implement this, but I understand your thoughts! :)

Comment: No problem. Have a great day ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

`reverse()` (an also `sort()`) is an in-place function, meaning it modify the content of the array calling it. It goes against react's immutable ideology, where datas are not to be changed after they're created.

I suggest you clone the array (and reverse the cloned array) before passing it into the component's props:

```
const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
  return {
    playedGames: state.userPlayedGames.playedGames.slice().reverse(),
    isLoading: state.isLoading,
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this.... I was unable to add a .slice().reverse() to the mapStateToProps  line as you suggested. I did however, add the .slice() into my code as stated above - and now my chart works as expected.  Could you let me know if you have successfully used .slice().reverse() the way you stated? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)` life Lifecycle method to reverse your 'playedGames' only the props actually instead of reverse on each refresh.

```js
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    // Any time the playedGames changes,
    // Reverse and store in the state
    if (props.playedGames !== state.playedGames) {
        const dataForChart = props.playedGames.reverse().map((game, index) => ({
            x: index,
            y: (total += parseFloat(game.profit)),
        }));

        return {
            dataForChart: dataForChart,
            playedGames: playedGames,
        };
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then use sorted data in the state to plot the graph.  (`this.state.dataForChart`)

Comment: Upon trying to implement your solutions. It ended up that because I am using Redux, I had issues. I think, if my state was being constructed locally it would have worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer using .splice().reverse() as seen below:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';

class ChartPage extends Component {
profitForChart = (props) => {
    let total = 0
    return this.props.playedGames.slice().reverse().map( (game, index) => ({
      x: index,
      y: total += parseFloat(game.profit)

    }))
  } 
render() {
   if(!this.props.playedGames) return <h1>Loading...</h1>
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const data = {
      datasets: [{
        data: this.profitForChart(),
        label: 'PROFIT'
    }],
    labels: this.props.playedGames.slice().reverse().map( game => (new Date(game.start_date_time)).toLocaleDateString()),
  }
  return(
      <div className={classes.root}

            <Line data={data} />

      </div>
  )
 }
}
const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
  return {
    playedGames: state.userPlayedGames.playedGames,
    isLoading: state.isLoading,
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = {
}
ChartPage.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
export default  compose(
  withStyles(styles, {
    name: 'ChartPage',
  }),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps))(withRouter(ChartPage));
```